# Automatically download files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, download, batch-processing

I'm trying to write a ruby script which automatically downloads some files from some server ever 30-45 minutes (to prevent overload) as long as my computer is turned on. It's possible that my computer might be turned off at some point, but the download should resume (probably re-download the current file).
I already have the file list but I can't figure out how to make such a script to run autonomously.
What are some ways I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "autonomously"?

Comment: I mean, I just want it to keep downloading without any intervention. I basically set it up on my OS and it does the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a cross platform scheduler you can give a try to [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) if you are on *nix systems you can also use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which is cron based.

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler.every '3h' do
  download_my_files_list
end
```

whenever syntax is similar all the tasks are included in a `scheduler.rb` file

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyFiles.download"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a cron job to invoke your ruby script every 30 or 45 minutes. then the ruby script can just focus on pick up a url from the file list and grap it.